# Select from one list only those present in another and order by second list - linq

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

I have two array..

```
var data1 = new[] { 
        new { Product = "Product 1", Year = 2009, Sales = 1212 },
        new { Product = "Product 2", Year = 2009, Sales = 522 },
        new { Product = "Product 1", Year = 2010, Sales = 1337 },
        new { Product = "Product 2", Year = 2011, Sales = 711 },
        new { Product = "Product 2", Year = 2012, Sales = 2245 },
        new { Product = "Product 3", Year = 2012, Sales = 1000 }
    };

var data2 = new[] { 
        new { Product = "Product 1", Year = 2009, Sales = 1212 },
        new { Product = "Product 1", Year = 2010, Sales = 1337 },
        new { Product = "Product 2", Year = 2011, Sales = 711 },
        new { Product = "Product 2", Year = 2012, Sales = 2245 }
    };
```

I want to group `data1` by `Product` and do a sum of the groups by `Sales` for only those products which are present in `data2` and order them the same way as they are in `data2`. Please note that even if a product is present in `data2`, all years present in `data1` for that product is not present in `data2` (eg.`{ Product = "Product 2", Year = 2009, Sales = 522 }`) and so the grouping and sum will have to happen on `data1`.

To just do the grouping and sum the below should work..

```
data1.GroupBy(x=>x.Product)
.Select(x=>new {Product=x.Key,Total= x.Sum(s=>s.Sales)})
```

But how do I ensure I select only products in data2 and order the result by `Product` as in data2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a different approach.

Since you want the final result to contain the products from the second list in the same order, I would start with getting `Distinct` products from the second list.

Although not stated explicitly in the documentation, the `Distinct` method (similar to `GroupBy`) yields the distinct elements in the order of the first occurrence of the unique element in the source, hence the result of the `Distinct` will be the products of the final result in the correct order.

Then I would use [`GroupJoin`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534297(v=vs.110).aspx) to correlate it with the first list, ending up with a quite efficient query:

```
var result = data2.Select(item => item.Product).Distinct()
    .GroupJoin(data1, product => product, item => item.Product, (product, group) =>
        new { Product = product, Sales = group.Sum(item => item.Sales) })
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need two things: First, you select the available products from your `data2`. For this, you can use the overload for `Select` which also gives the index of the matching element.

Second, you filter your `data1` based on the products in `data2` and perform the grouping afterwards. As a last step you add a new property `CorrespondingIndex` which matches the index of the product in `data2`. This index can be used for ordering your `data1` list based on the ordering of products in `data2`.

```
  var productsWithIndex = data2
    .Select(x => x.Product)
    .Distinct()
    .Select((p, idx) => new {Product = p, Index = idx});

  var filteredProducts = data1
    .Where(x => productsWithIndex.Select(p => p.Product).Contains(x.Product))
    .GroupBy(x => x.Product)
    .Select(x => new
    {
      Product = x.Key,
      Total = x.Sum(s => s.Sales),
      CorrespondingIndex = productsWithIndex.Single(p => p.Product == x.Key).Index
    })
    .OrderBy(x => x.CorrespondingIndex);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pehaps you don't even need to go in that much detail, as user1384848 went.
You might get along with something much simpler as this:

```
var result =
                data1.Where(e => data2.Any(x => x.Product == e.Product))
                    .GroupBy(arg => arg.Product,
                        (name, products) => new {Product = name, Total = products.Sum(e => e.Sales)})
                    .OrderBy(d => d.Product);
```

Comment: will this not order it by data1 product order